# Distribution of multivariate Gaussian conditional on value of linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Given a Gaussian random vector
$X \in \mathbf{R}^p \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol\mu, \boldsymbol\Sigma)$, a matrix $\mathbf{K} \in \mathbf{R}^{q \times p}$,
and a vector $y \in \mathbf{R}^q$,
I'd like to find the distribution of $\tilde X = (X \mid \boldsymbol{K} X = y)$
while assuming that $\operatorname{rank}(\boldsymbol\Sigma) = p$ and $\operatorname{rank}(\boldsymbol{K}) \le q < p$. Ideally without having to (psuedo-)invert any singular matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first let's recall a standard formula of the conditional distribution of $X$ given $W$ when we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ W \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\  \nu \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma & T \\ T^\top & \Upsilon \end{bmatrix} \right).
$$
In that case we have
$$
X\mid W \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \mu + T\Upsilon^{-1}(W-\nu), \Sigma-T\Upsilon^{-1}T^\top \right).
$$

Now apply this to the case where $W=KX$, so that $\mathbb E(W)=K\mathbb E(X)$ and $\operatorname{var}(W) = K\operatorname{var}(X)K^\top$.